# rails: Updating a record nested two join tables deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem that's really confusing me.

I have four models, a Workout model, an Exercise model, a workout_exercise join model, and a workout_exercise_set model.

I can add exercises to workouts through the workout_exercises join table. Now I'm trying to add sets to exercises in workouts, which is what the workout_exercises_sets table is for.

Here's an example.

```
Workout   
  Exercise 1
    Set 1
    Set 2
    Set 3   
  Exercise 2
    Set 1
    Set 2
    Set 3   
  Exercise 3
    etc.
```

In `workouts/edit.html.erb` I have a form where I can see all the exercises in the workout, and edit the number of sets by using `form_for` and `fields_for`, but when I try to update an exercise or the entire workout I get a `MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in WorkoutsController#update` that says `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: workout_exercise_sets`. I can't figure out how to get past this. I know I'm editing a workout, but I'm not trying to write to a field called `workout_exercise_sets`, so I'm really confused here. I really appreciate any guidance. All relevant code is below.

`workout/edit.html.erb:`

```
<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %></br>
        <%= f.fields_for :workout_exercises do |s| %>
                <%= s.object.exercise.name %></b>
                    <%= s.fields_for :workout_exercise_sets do |set| %> 
                        <%= set.label :set_number %>:
                        <%= set.number_field :set_number %>     
                        <%= set.label :reps %>:
                        <%= set.number_field :repetitions %>
                        <%= set.label :rest_time %>(seconds):
                        <%= set.number_field :rest_time %>
                        <%= set.submit %>
                    <% end %>
                <%= s.hidden_field :_destroy %>
                <%= link_to "Remove exercise?", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
        <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the workout model:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :exercises_attributes, :workout_exercises_attributes, :exercise_order, :description

  has_many :workout_exercises, dependent: :destroy, :order => "exercise_order DESC"
  has_many :exercises, through: :workout_exercises

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_exercises, allow_destroy: :true

end
```

Here is the exercise model:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description

  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :workouts, through: :workout_exercises

  validates :name,        uniqueness: :true, presence: :true
  validates :description, uniqueness: :true, presence: :true

end
```

Here is the workout_exercise model:

```
class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :exercise_id, :workout_id

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :workout

  has_many :workout_exercise_sets, dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_exercise_sets, allow_destroy: :true

end
```

and finally, here is the workout_exercise_sets model:

```
class WorkoutExerciseSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :repetitions, :rest_time, :set_number, :workout_exercise_id

  belongs_to :workout_exercise
end
```

And for good measure, here is a diagram of the DB: [image]

Comment: Didn't my solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your `workout_excercise.rb` file, you should add `:workout_exercise_sets_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` list.

```
class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :exercise_id, :workout_id, :workout_exercise_sets_attributes

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :workout

  has_many :workout_exercise_sets, dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_exercise_sets, allow_destroy: :true

end
```

Comment: Good idea. It didn't change the error message unfortunately. On a related note, this line of code `accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_exercise_sets, allow_destroy: :true` in `workoutExercise.rb` causes `fields_for :workout_exercise_sets do |set|` to output nothing for some reason.

Comment: Are you usig `build` to create nested elements?

Comment: I think you'd better checkout this page: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: You have to `build` nested attributes in order them to appear in the form.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake on my part. I hadn't put any records in the table yet, so wasn't seeing any output. For future reference, there is a great railscast on the nested forms.